how can I get all data of collection and subcollection and insert them into one list
I have this database of nested collections doctors --> visits
 & 
I want to get all data of collection and subcollection and insert them into one list to show them using ListView later.
This is data model"
class allReport {
  late String? date;
  late String? doctorNote;
  String? doctoreName;
  late String? marketerNote;
  late String? id;

  allReport(
      {
      required this.date,
      required this.doctorNote,
      required this.marketerNote,
      required this.id,
      required this.doctoreName});

  static allReport fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json, String id, String doctoreName) =>
      allReport(
        id: id,
        doctoreName: doctoreName,
        doctorNote: json['doctorNote'],
        date: json['date'],
        marketerNote: json['marketerNote'],
      );
}

this is my code to get the data
I'm trying to use   doc.reference.parent.parent   of each visits documents to get it's parent id then get that parent data as below:
  List<allReport> _docReports = [];
  
  List<allReport> _filtereddocReports = [];


 Future<List<allReport>> getAlldocsData() async {
    var col = await _firestore.collectionGroup('visits');

    var snapshot_child = await col.get();
     snapshot_child.docs.map((doc) async {

      var ChildDocument = doc;

    var snapshot_parent =  await _firestore
          .collection('doctors')
          .doc(ChildDocument.reference.parent.parent?.id)
          .get();

      _docReports =  allReport.fromJson(
           ChildDocument.data() ,snapshot_parent.data()?['name'] ,doc.reference.parent.parent?.id ?? '') as List<allReport>;

    }).toList();

    
    print('**********************${_docReports.map((e) => e.doctoreName)}');
    
    setState(() {
      _filtereddocReports = _docReports;
    });
    return _filtereddocReports;

  }

The code is not printing any data, instead is printing "out of memory" error - or sometimes app keep crashing. I really have no idea what could be the problem.

If you're getting an out of memory error, it seems you're loading more data than your device has memory for. The solution is to load less data.

Have you tried Frank's recommendation? Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo I've tried to get only these data: allReport.fromJson(
ChildDocument.data()['doctorNote'] ,snapshot_parent.data()?['name'] ,doc.reference.parent.parent?.id ?? ''); but i still get the same error:   'Unable to create protected region in stack for implicit overflow check. Reason: Out of memory size:  4096'

Have you tried to call limit(10), for example, on your query? Do you get the same behavior?

@AlexMamo I tried it and I got this error :  Unhandled Exception: type 'allReport' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

Then you should the result to be of type List<allReport> and not of type allReport, right?

@AlexMamo  I already did that but still getting the error, please check the code above

Then it means that the result that is coming is not of the correct type. It should be of tye List<allReport>.

@AlexMamo I don't know where to put this part "_docReports =  allReport.fromJson(...)  "  because I got this error-->  "A value of type 'allReport' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List" that means I'm not getting a list from the nested query and what I really want to do is getting a list of all data of the two collections together
